# PHP + JS + AJAX: Unexpected token { in JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

On trying to return some data from a `GET` request via `AJAX`, I'm continuously greeted with this nasty error message `...Unexpected token { in JSON...` and I can clearly see where it's coming from. Note that this only happens if I have more than one(1) item being returned from the database. If I only have one(1) item I am able to access it `data.id`, `data.user_name`, so on and so forth.

```
{  
   "id":"39",
   "user_id":"19",
   "user_name":"Brandon",
   "content":"Second Post",
   "date_created":"2018-01-24 21:41:15"
}/* NEEDS TO BE A ',' RIGHT HERE */ {  
   "id":"37",
   "user_id":"19",
   "user_name":"Brandon",
   "content":"First",
   "date_created":"2018-01-24 15:19:28"
}
```

But I can't figure out how to fix it. Working with data, arrays, and objects is an artform I have yet to master.

### JAVASCRIPT (AJAX)

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/mouthblog/test.php');
xhr.onload = () => {
  if (xhr.status == 200) {
    const data = xhr.responseText;
    const jsonPrs = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(jsonPrs);
  } else {
    console.log('ERROR');
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

### PHP (this is where the data is coming from)

```
<?php

class BlogRoll extends Connection {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->connect();

    $sql    = "SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `user_name`, `content`, `date_created`
               FROM `posts`
               ORDER BY `date_created` DESC";
    $query  = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $result = $query->execute();

    if ($result) {
      while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        echo json_encode($row);
      }
    } else {
      echo 'NO POSTS TO DISPLAY';
    }
  }
}
```

I've been at this for a couple of hours now, everything similar to my problem on SO seems to be something different and I can't really find a decent plain JavaScript tutorial on returning real data. Everyone wants to use jQuery.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with jQuery.  Your problem is that your JSON is not valid.  JSON must be a _single_ object.  You need an array.

Comment: Right, I wasn't saying that about jQuery, just clarifying I want a plain JavaScript solution/explanation. Do I need to push that from my PHP side or from the JS side? I've tried using `array_push($array, $row)`, where $array is an empty array and $row is what is being returned from the database in the `while` loop and I just get another syntax error `unexpected < in JSON`

Comment: Figure out why there is a `<` and get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code is failing is because you are using

```
echo json_encode($row);
```

This will echo an array for every row, but it is not valid JSON. I have corrected your PHP code (note: it has not been tested)

```
<?php

class BlogRoll extends Connection {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->connect();

    $sql    = "SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `user_name`, `content`, `date_created`
               FROM `posts`
               ORDER BY `date_created` DESC";
    $query  = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $result = $query->execute();

    $returnArray = array(); // Create a blank array to put our rows into

    if ($result) {
      while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        array_push($returnArray, $row); // For every row, put that into our array
      }
    } else {
        // Send the JSON back that we didn't find any data using 'message'
        $returnArray = array(
            "message" => "No data was found"
        );
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8'); // Setting headers is good :)
    exit(json_encode($returnArray)); // Exit with our JSON. This makes sure nothing else is sent and messes up our response.

  }
}
```

Also, you stated this:

```
If I only have one(1) item I am able to access it data.id, data.user_name, so on and so forth.
```

That is correct because the array only contains that one item. The example you would access it via data.0.id, data.1.id, data.2.id, etc as each row is in its own array.

Comment: Thank you for this, very solid solution.

Comment: Interesting thing that `exit(json_encode(...))`. I didn't knew this trick ;-)

Comment: @aendeerei It terminates the current script, so basically like a giant return, but globally. You can alos give it an integer or string to print right before exiting.

Comment: I'd like to throw in that it seems you can't actually return it. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` which might be obvious to some, but `echo json_encode($returnArray);` works just fine. Although I will use the `exit()` function from now on.

Comment: @CodyRobinson Thanks for the explanation. Indeed, like Brandon, I, too, plan to test and use it in the future.

Comment: @aendeerei Just an FYI if you look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php it explains that it is equivalent to `die()` and vice versa.

Comment: @BrandonBenefield Where are you getting the unexpected end of JSON input at?

Comment: @CodyRobinson `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload` when clicking on the `debugger` link, it shows an empty page with a `red X` to signal an error, but no text. And it's coming from `const jsonPrs = JSON.parse(data);` in my `JavaScript`.

Comment: @BrandonBenefield can you paste the JSON from the exit(json_encode()) and echo json_encode()?

Comment: @BrandonBenefield Do `console.log(xhr.responseText)` before `const data = ...`. And use `var` instead of `const`. Any error viewable now?

Comment: @BrandonBenefield the JSON you sent me are identical and both valid. I have no clue why it would be erroring out when you use exit()

Comment: No not when using exit(), must've misunderstood, errors when i `return`.

Comment: @BrandonBenefield yea, unless you are using echo myFunction() return will not display the output to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You must print only once, e.g. a data "package" from which you will reference the items on the client-side correspondingly. But in your code you're actually printing for each row a data "package".

The solution is to create an array and save the whole fetched data into it. After that the array should be json-encoded and printed.

```
if ($result) {
    // Save the fetched data into an array (all at once).
    $fetchedData = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Json-encode the whole array - once.
    // header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    echo json_encode($fetchedData);
} else {
    echo 'NO POSTS TO DISPLAY';
}
```